# Каждый раз добавлять записи в файл csv при запуске

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
try:
    resultBeforeAll = dataframe[dataframe['status_id'].isin(dataFrameWithErrorStatus[0])]
    resultBeforeAll.to_csv('errors.csv', sep=';')
except Exception as ex:
    print(Fore.CYAN + '[Error] in write file', ex)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать чтобы при повторном запуске скрипта, он не перезаписывал данные в файле а добавлял и удалял одинаковые записи?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530542/how-to-add-pandas-data-to-an-existing-csv-file

Comment: А что такое "одинаковые записи" в вашем понимании? Так то ну делаете `pd.concat` старых данных и новых. Избавление от дубликатов - через `groupby`. Но потом вероятно нужно будет отсортировать, порядок следования записей может измениться.